# Radio button selection to show table on next output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

In my shiny app, I am uploading different types of files which I do want to process and display the result on different output sections. But the **second output** is depended on the **first output** result. In my second output, I am filtering the first table using column names. Now the problem I have is some files I am uploading don't have the columns I am using to subset for second output, they have been moved to the first row which means once I upload a file with different columns I should replace the columns existing with first row them filter results for the second output.  Here is my app :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv')),
      # radio button to show either row or replaced column table
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Replace columns"),
                   choices = list("Raw table" = 1, "change columns" = 2), 
                   selected = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('filtered')
    )
  )
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  myData <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })


  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())       
  })

  #Replace columns  reactive event
  replaceColumns <- eventReactive(input$radio,{
    #Change row to column and delete first row
    colnames(myData()) <-myData()[1,]
    df = myData()[-1, ]
    df
  })


  data2<- reactive({
    # Select columns of the dataframe
    df1 <- select(myData(),mpg,cyl,wt)
    df1

  })

  #Output based on either raw or replaced column table
  output$filtered <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data2())       
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

How can Use radio button or if there is another better way, so that when I upload a file and I see it has right columns, it automatically displays in first output, and when I click *raw table* In radio button  it proceeds to filter and give  **filtered output** and If uploaded file does not have right columns I click on *change columns* so that to replace columns  with the first row of the table then filter and show filtered output?

The way I want my app to behave is, when I upload a file, it displays and if the file has right columns, then I click *raw table* on radio button which now proceeds to filter and display filtered output in second output  but if I can see the file uploaded has wrong columns then I click on c*hange columns* in radio button which will replace columns with the first row and then proceed to filtered results in second output. What I simply mean is. I want the second output to depend on what I select on radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, the first `DT` output shows the table as loaded (with good or bad names). One approach is to fix the column names silently:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput(
      'file1',
      'Choose CSV File',
      accept = c('text/csv',
                 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                 '.csv')
    )),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('filtered')
    )
  )
))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })

  # Approach 1: fix the data silently
  # Replace column names if needed
  fixData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- myData()

    expectedColumns <- c("mpg", "cyl", "wt")
    if (!all(expectedColumns %in% colnames(myData()))) {
      #Change row to column and delete first row
      colnames(df) <- df[1, ]
      df = df[-1,]
    }  
    df
  })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    # Select columns of the dataframe
    df1 <- select(fixData(), mpg, cyl, wt)
    df1
  })

  #Output based on either raw or replaced column table
  output$filtered <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data2())
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Another approach is to use radio buttons as you have planned:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv')),
      # radio button to show either row or replaced column table
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Replace columns"),
                   choices = list("Raw table" = 1, "Change column names" = 2), 
                   selected = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('filtered')
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })

  # Approach 2: click on an radioButton to fix the data

  fixData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- myData()
    if (input$radio == 2) {
      #Change row to column and delete first row
      colnames(df) <- df[1,]
      df = df[-1, ]
    }
    df
  })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())       
  })

  data2<- reactive({
    # Select columns of the dataframe
    df1 <- select(fixData(),mpg,cyl,wt)
    df1
  })

  #Output based on either raw or replaced column table
  output$filtered <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data2())       
  })
}
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```